# Bash -eq doesn't work, maybe because of cal

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
d="$(date +%d)"
#wrong one:
#an="$(cal | awk '/[0-9]/ {print $2}' | tail -2)"
# fixed one:
an="$(cal | col -b | sed 's/_//g' | awk '/[0-9]/ {print $2}' | tail -2)"
for e in $an
do
  if [ "$d" -eq "$e" ]; then
    i=1
  fi
done

echo i=$i
```

The problem is with $an/$e but i don't understand why and how to fix it. I've looked and it don't have any spaces, they are numbers however bash don't think this way.

<< EDIT >>

Ok i agree, maybe i've chosen the wrong way to do it, just thought that with cal it would be simple.
Its part of a bigger script so i need to get a result from it so that script could proceed further down the code.
I need to get 2 last mondays, tuesadays,..., or sundays and compare it with today, if the sate is the same give this info to the script.

Comment: What problem are you having? I get `i=1`, isn't that correct?

Comment: To debug a shell script, run it with `bash -x scriptname`, it will show every line as it's executed.

Comment: @User2707431 what is it supposed to do? detect the last two mondays on months that don't end on a sunday? (else detect the last monday)

Comment: i have i=0, its supposed to be 1. In my case if statement doesn't work even though $e has the same digital data as $d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cal uses overstrike to underline today `cal | less` if you don't 
have an ascii printer handy.

You need to filter that out first.

col is the tool for that

```
i=0
d="$(date +%d)"
an="$(cal | col -b | awk '/[0-9]/ {print $2}' | tail -2)"
for e in $an
do
  if [ "$d" -eq "$e" ]; then
    i=1
  fi
done
```

Alternative is today one of the last two mondays in a month.

```
 # must be GNU date
 (( `date -d '2 weeks' +' i = %d < 14 && %w == 1 '` ))
```

This expression sets i to 1 or 0 and returns true or false
if you want the "sunday bug" use `13 days` `%w == 0` instead of `2 weeks` `%w == 1`

Comment: The version of `cal` I have here on Ubuntu seems to avoid adding any formatting when it is connected to a pipe.  I can reproduce the same behavior on a fairly old Debian (man page indicates 2004).

Comment: cal is probably the wrong tool for whatever this task is supposed to be.I expect gnu date and bash are all that's actually needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, GNU `date` is not ubiquitous, and its date parser is quirky.  I could not find a simple, obvious way to make it print the last Monday of the month.  (That is not to say there isn't one, but I could not discover it through trial and error.)

Comment: @tripleee, you don't need to find the last monday, all the tests are being done against today, so just check if is if next week is the first Monday of next Month. `date -d '1 week'`

Comment: On my older Debian box (coreutils 5.2.1) `date -d 'next monday`' returns today (when today is a Monday) but `date -d '2 weeks'` works fine.

Comment: sorry about that curve ball, I was saving before cheking my comments

Comment: NVM, the real lesson here I guess is that date parsing in shell scripts is brittle business.

Comment: dates, and times (if DST is involved) are slippery things in any language.  I try to always look for a mathematical proof of correctness.

Comment: col didn't do the trick and another expression doesn't work for me on Kubuntu 14.04

Comment: @user2707431 huh? it only detects the last 2 Mondays in the month, yesterday was not one of them

Comment: oh wait i overlooked it, "col -b | sed 's/_//g'" did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you explained which problem you are trying to solve.  The following might be a better way to tell "is today one of the last two Mondays of this month?" which I assume is what your code is attempting to do.

```
cal | awk -v d=$(date +%d) '$2==d { x=2 }
    /[0-9]/ { x-- }
    END { exit (!(x >= 0)) }' && i=1
```

There are certainly multiple ways to slice this, but the above refactors most of the logic into Awk -- since you are using it anyway, use it to its full potential.

Comment: This does not attempt to fix any bugs in the original logic, because it's not clear what the bugs are when we don't know what it's supposed to do.  In particular, the "month ends on Sunday" case pointed out by @Jasen is not addressed differently by my code.